# Copying in Vectors to a Thread

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust

Considering the following code, I wish to have access to both `client` and `requests` within my thread, currently I do not:

```
for _x in 0..100 {
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            let start = time::precise_time_s();

            let res = client.get("http://jacob.uk.com")
                .header(Connection::close()) 
                .send().unwrap();

            let end = time::precise_time_s();

            requests.push(Request::new(end-start));
        });

        handle.join().unwrap()
    }
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
   Compiling Herd v0.1.0 (file:///Users/jacobclark/Desktop/LearningRust/Herd)
src/main.rs:41:23: 41:29 error: capture of moved value: `client`
src/main.rs:41             let res = client.get("http://jacob.uk.com")
                                     ^~~~~~
src/main.rs:38:41: 48:10 note: `client` moved into closure environment here because it has type `[closure(())]`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:38         let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
src/main.rs:39             let start = time::precise_time_s();
src/main.rs:40         
src/main.rs:41             let res = client.get("http://jacob.uk.com")
src/main.rs:42                 .header(Connection::close()) 
src/main.rs:43                 .send().unwrap();
               ...
src/main.rs:38:41: 48:10 help: perhaps you meant to use `clone()`?
src/main.rs:47:13: 47:21 error: capture of moved value: `requests`
src/main.rs:47             requests.push(Request::new(end-start));
                           ^~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:38:41: 48:10 note: `requests` moved into closure environment here because it has type `[closure(())]`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:38         let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
src/main.rs:39             let start = time::precise_time_s();
src/main.rs:40         
src/main.rs:41             let res = client.get("http://jacob.uk.com")
src/main.rs:42                 .header(Connection::close()) 
src/main.rs:43                 .send().unwrap();
               ...
src/main.rs:38:41: 48:10 help: perhaps you meant to use `clone()`?
src/main.rs:53:24: 53:32 error: use of moved value: `requests`
src/main.rs:53     Request::mean_time(requests);
                                      ^~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:38:41: 48:10 note: `requests` moved into closure environment here because it has type `[closure(())]`, which is non-copyable
src/main.rs:38         let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
src/main.rs:39             let start = time::precise_time_s();
src/main.rs:40         
src/main.rs:41             let res = client.get("http://jacob.uk.com")
src/main.rs:42                 .header(Connection::close()) 
src/main.rs:43                 .send().unwrap();
               ...
src/main.rs:38:41: 48:10 help: perhaps you meant to use `clone()`?
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
Could not compile `Herd`
```

.

Comment: The client I am not too bothered about, in this case I'm more concerned with the `requests` vector.

Comment: Your example is not nearly sufficient enough. We have *no way* of telling what the type of `client` or `results` are, for example, which is **very important to help you**. Please strive to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably one that compiles on [the playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, minimal examples are really useful:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mut items = Vec::new();

    for _ in 0..100 {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            items.push(());
        });
    }
}
```

So what's the problem here? Well, you're moving `items` into a closure 100 times - but you can only move it once!

To share data across multiple threads, you need

- To remove data races - put it in a `Mutex` (or don't mutate it).
- To keep it alive - put it in an `Arc` (**A**tomically **R**eference-**C**ounted pointer).

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let items = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let thread_items = items.clone();

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            thread_items.lock().unwrap().push(());
        });

        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    println!("{:?}", items);
}
```